# How to achieve this type of scroll effect?

Tags: javascript, css

Can you please help me in achieving exactly this kind of effect?
Effect :

https://www.aristidebenoist.com/

I have achieved this similar effect using Linear Interpolation, but my method has a drawback. If the user scrolls with more power or force on his mousewheel the website will scroll with ease but covers most part of the website as much as the native scroll covers with the same force. The link provided above has applied some limit to such thing and no matter how much forcefully you scroll, it will always scroll with the limited intensity which the developer has applied.

Here's the link to my code :

https://codepen.io/Neil98/pen/VREJZb

```
function lerp (a,b,n) {
return (1 - n) * a + n * b;
} // LERP FUNCTION

dx = lerp(dx,sx,0.07); // sx = scroll position, dx = container position
dy = lerp(dy,sy,0.07);
```

PS: If you still didn't get it, try and scroll harder on both my example and the website provided, you will see the website limits you no matter how hard you scroll.

Comment: the scrolling is decoupled from the native scrolling, in that it never uses values from the event, other than to detect the direction of scrolling. it also uses precomputed stop/start positions for each animation. such scrolling technique uses a time based animation function with callbacks for `onUpdate` and `onComplete`. so you would plug your easing function in and then `onUpdate` would receive the offset for the next scroll, then you just `window.scroll(pos,0)`. i can give you an example if you've never seen this animation pattern before.

Comment: I got your point about getting offset as his code has multiple containers having transform property unlike mine with only one main container. But still didn't get it fully, would love to see the example

Comment: then he is using the offset of the container as scroll start, and offset of the bottom of the container (or just offsetTop + height of container) as the start and end positions for each animation. this is probably the easy way to do it, but you could do it manually by dividing the page height into chunks of `n` which are range offsets. anyway here is such an animation function https://jsfiddle.net/qohgey76/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to understand this and apply. It seems difficult.

Comment: if you view source of his code, you can see he's not using the solution i proposed, but instead just using a throttle function so that only a certain amount of scrolls happen per second, and then he manually sets the scroll position from those events. its hard to read but the solution is all there you just gotta find it. it also appears to be written in angular.js v1.x. i would recommend grabbing his source and prettyfying it and walking through it to understand.

Comment: yes, I tried to see his source code and it seemed to be something I haven't studied yet. I am new to programming, I'll figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you help me with a working example ?? How will the other elements adapt this, this seems so confusing @r3wt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194382/discussion-between-ryuzaki98-and-r3wt).